# Having a problen to develop lockscreen for android

Tags: android, locking, screen, lockscreen

I want to develop an android application that will be an alternative lockscreen.
I searched a lot and i couldn't found an explanation about how to make an app to work like a lockscreen. I understand that there is no official android API for lockscreens, but there must be way, because there are a lot of alternative lockscreens applications in the market.
Does someone know how could i make my app work like a lockscreen? Or if there is a basic code out there of lockscreen app that i can learn from it how to do it?
Thanks a lot (:

Answer (score 0):

The way this is usually accomplished is creating an app that becomes the home application and then when the screen is turned on display your custom lockscreen and hide it when the user successfully unlocks it so they can use the device.

Make sure to take a look at the [numerous questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lockscreen) that are very similar to this.